# How many friendly fire kills before you're kicked?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In hardcore team deathmatch, I've noticed other players being kicked for persistent team killing. Is the threshold an absolute number or a ratio? I've noticed that people with 4:0 get kicked straight out.

Also, do collateral damage kills, eg kills with a claymore which also kill one of your own?

Comment: Looking to see how many people you can annoy before you need to stop? lol xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can team kill team members a maximum of three times. The third time this happens you will be kicked.

Collateral damage kills count too, because, you could shoot your claymore purposefully to kill a teammate.

There is also the edge case of where you are the host and you won't be kicked. Instead, on action of your third team kill, you will die, and have a 20 second wait, before being added to the respawn cycle. The amount of time you have to wait will increase for every subsequent team kill. I think this is by adding 20 seconds for each subsequent team kill.

You also can't kill someone as soon as the round begins, I think this is around 30 seconds immunity. If you kill them, you will instead die. But this doesn't add to your team kill count and it also doesn't add 20 seconds or give you a 20 second wait.

**NOTE: This only occurs for XBox 360 and PS3. PC users have noticed up to 5 team kills before being kicked**

Comment: People *experimented*? Glad I wasn't playing on those servers! :)

Comment: @Alex Sometimes I will shoot annoying team-mates if I know I won't get kicked. I.e. team killed me

Comment: i've been kicked out games for shooting just one teammate

Comment: I was kicked after just 2 team kills.